# Retrofit 2. Как узнать, что пришел ответ на запрос?

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

Задача следующая: делается асинхронный вызов, в результате которого получаются некоторые данные. С момента отправки запроса до момента получения ответа в основном потоке нужно сделать паузу, чтобы дождаться получения этих данных и корректно их обработать. Как это можно реализовать?
Я пробовал создавать булеву переменную, которая в начале вызова была false и только в конце становилась true, а в основном потоке делал пустой цикл, который ждал пока она не станет true. Но ничего не вышло, приложение зависало.
Код: из диалогового окна делаем запрос `getAuthorization()`, после того как авторизовались нужно сделать запрос `getUserInfo()`

```
public void onClick(View view) {
            ((MainActivity)getActivity()).showWaitDialog();
            String login = etUsername.getText().toString();
            String password = etPassword.getText().toString();
            Boolean rememberMe = chbRemember.isChecked();
            if (rememberMe){
                savePref(PREF_REMEMBER_ME, true);
                savePref(PREF_LOGIN, login);
                savePref(PREF_PASSWORD, password);
            }
            ((MainActivity)getActivity()).getAuthorization(login, password, rememberMe);
            ((MainActivity)getActivity()).waitForRequest();
            switch (((MainActivity)getActivity()).getStatus()){
                case "ok":
                    ((MainActivity)getActivity()).getUserInfo();
                    ((MainActivity)getActivity()).waitForRequest();
                    switch (((MainActivity)getActivity()).getStatus()){
                        case "ok":
                            ((MainActivity)getActivity()).onLogin();
                            break;
                        case "error":
                            tvAlert.setText(((MainActivity) getActivity()).getError().getMessage());
                            break;
                        case "NoResponce":
                            tvAlert.setText("Сервер не отвечает");
                            break;
                        case "Failure":
                            tvAlert.setText("Не удалось обработать запрос. Проверьте подключение к Интернет");
                            break;
                    }
                    break;
                case "error":
                    tvAlert.setText(((MainActivity) getActivity()).getError().getMessage());
                    break;
                case "NoResponce":
                    tvAlert.setText("Сервер не отвечает");
                    break;
                case "Failure":
                    tvAlert.setText("Не удалось обработать запрос. Проверьте подключение к Интернет");
                    break;
            }
            ((MainActivity)getActivity()).hideWaitDialog();
        }
```

Это код "ожидалки":

```
public void waitForRequest(){
        do{} while (!requestDone);
    }
```

Это пример кода запроса, второй аналогичен:

```
public void getAuthorization(String login, String password, Boolean rememberMe){
        requestDone=false;
        JSONLoginPassword jsonLoginPassword = new JSONLoginPassword(login, password, rememberMe);
        MainActivity.getApi().authorization(jsonLoginPassword).enqueue(new Callback<MyResponce>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<MyResponce> call, Response<MyResponce> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    status = response.body().getStatus();
                    switch (status) {
                        case "ok":        //Если статус ok, сохраняем токен
                            String token = response.body().getData().toString();
                            PrefManager.savePref(PrefManager.PREF_TOKEN, token);
                            error.setCode("NoError");
                            error.setMessage("Запрос успешен. Данные получены");
                            requestDone=true;
                            break;
                        case "error":    //Если статус error, парсим и сохраняем ошибку
                            try {
                                error = new JSONParser(response.body().getData()).getError();
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            requestDone=true;
                            break;
                    }
                } else {
                    status = "NoResponce";
                    error.setCode(String.valueOf(response.code()));
                    error.setMessage(String.valueOf(response.body()));
                    requestDone=true;
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<MyResponce> call, Throwable t) {
                status = "Failure";
                error.setCode(String.valueOf(t));
                error.setMessage("Не удалось выполнить запрос. Программная ошибка");
                requestDone=true;
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Добавьте ваш код

Comment: Главный поток нельзя ни заставлять ждать, ни усыплять, ни нагружать тяжёлой работой. Да и не нужно -  то что Вы хотите сделать по окончании запроса запускайте в его колбэке. То есть тот код, что после `waitForRequest();` вынесите в отдельный метод и вызывайте его в `onResponse` и `onFailure`.

Comment: Изначально я так и делал, но потом чтобы сделать код более понятным решил переписать как в примере выше, но возникла описываемая проблема. Если решения не будет, придется последовать вашему совету.